# xpath regresa un valor diferente python

Tags: python, xpath, python-requests

Estoy tratando de obtener este valor con xpath

Nuevo  -  126 vendidos

las rutas que devuelven este valor pueden ser cualquiera de estas

```
//div/dl/div[@class="item-conditions"]

//*[@id="short-desc"]/div/dl/div

//div[1]/dl/div[1][@class="item-conditions"]/text()
```

el valor lo obtengo correctamente con scrape similar y con xpath helper el problema pasa cuando hago la consulta con python

```
url = 'url del sitio'
        req = requests.get(url)

        tree = html.fromstring(req.content)

        numero_ventas = tree.xpath('cualquiera de las rutas de xpath de arriba')
        print(numero_ventas)
```

devuelve este valor:

```
['\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t13\n\t\t\t\tvendidos\n\t\t\t\n\t\t']
```

este es el html

```
<div class="short-description__floating non-fixed" style="">

<dl class="vip-title-info">
    <div class="item-conditions xh-highlight">

            Nuevo



                &nbsp;-&nbsp;

            126
            vendidos

    </div>
</dl>
```

estoy usando python3 con mac os 10.14.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, no he podido replicar tu resultado con las expresiones XPath y el HTML que proporcionas.

1. `//div/dl/div[@class="item-conditions"]` devuelve lista vacía, porque el elemento `div` en cuestión tiene `class="item-conditions xh-highlight"`, que no es igual a `"item-conditions"`, tendrías que haber usado `contains()` (luego lo arreglo).
2. `//*[@id="short-desc"]/div/dl/div` devuelve lista vacía porque no hay en el HTML de ejemplo que has pegado ningún elemento con ese `id`.
3. `//div[1]/dl/div[1][@class="item-conditions"]/text()` devuelve lista vacía por la misma razón que el primero.

Si arreglo el primero:

```
from lxml import html
tree = html.fromstring(ejemplo)
e1 = '//div/dl/div[contains(@class, "item-conditions")]'

numero_ventas = tree.xpath(e1)
print(numero_ventas)
```

Obtengo:

```
[<Element div at 0x7f16c2641bd8>]
```

Es decir, una lista con un elemento, pero no con el texto de ese elemento. Podría acceder al texto con:

```
numero_ventas[0].text
```

Y eso retorna la cadena `'\n\n            Nuevo\n\n\n\n                \xa0-\xa0\n\n            126\n            vendidos\n\n    '`, que es correcta pues el HTML que has puesto de ejemplo efectivamente contiene muchos espacios en blanco y retornos de carro dentro del `div` en cuestión.

El mismo texto podríamos haber extraido con la tercera opción, una vez arreglada:

```
e3 = '//div[1]/dl/div[1][contains(@class, "item-conditions")]/text()'  
numero_ventas = tree.xpath(e3)
print(numero_ventas)
```

Produce una lista con un solo elemento que es el texto en cuestión:

```
['\n\n            Nuevo\n\n\n\n                \xa0-\xa0\n\n            126\n            vendidos\n\n    ']
```

En mi caso salen espacios donde a tí te salían tabs, pero básicamente es lo mismo (supongo que los tabs se han convertido en espacios al copiar&pegar el ejemplo).

Ambos son resultados esperables, pero no coinciden con el que tú muestras, en el que el texto "Nuevo" ha desaparecido.

En todo caso, entiendo que quieres eliminar todos esos espacios y retornos de carro intermedios. Esto ya no es trabajo de Xpath, sino de un procesamiento de cadenas con python. Por ejemplo, puedes hacer un `.split()`, que te romperá el texto por todos los caracteres "blancos" (espacios, tabuladores, retornos de carro) o secuencias de blancos, dejándote una lista con tan solo las palabras, para después hacer un `" ".join()` de esa lista que vuelva a intercalar un espacio entre palabras.

Por ejemplo así, tras el resultado del caso 3:

```
limpio = " ".join(numero_ventas[0].split())
```

La cadena resultante en `limpio` es:

```
'Nuevo - 126 vendidos'
```

Comment: hola que tal abulafia mil gracias por la ayuda y el tiempo aprendí mucho con tu explicacion mil gracias